# In cloudflare worker how to get data from url

Tags: node.js, cloudflare-workers

How to get data params from url and decrypt using the function below in cloudflare worker.`https://SOMEID.srv10.workers.dev/hash/` So i want to get hash and decrypt that using that function.

```
async function decryptData(encryptedData, password) {
  try {
    // split the IV off from the end (delimited using ::)
    encryptedComponents= encryptedData.split("::")

    const data = hexStringToUint8Array(encryptedComponents[0])
    const iv = hexStringToUint8Array(encryptedComponents[1])
    
    const passwordKey = await getPasswordKey(password, ['decrypt'])
    const decryptedContent = await crypto.subtle.decrypt(
      {
        name: 'AES-CBC',
        iv: iv,
      },
      passwordKey,
      data,
    )
    return arraybufferToString(decryptedContent)
  } catch (e) {
    throw e
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the _hash_ in `https://SOMEID.srv10.workers.dev/hash/` going to be the actual hash? or are you appending it as a query? e.g. `https://SOMEID.srv10.workers.dev/hash/?id=98hb23498bh23fdng9dun`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your hash is a query parameter you can simply read it like so:

```
// convert the worker request url into a URL object
const url = new URL(request.url);
// read the encrypted data from the query param
const encryptedData = url.searchParams.get('hash');
// call your function
await decryptData(encryptedData, '<your-password-here>');
```